# Set the default price of all in-app-products in the currency of the target account

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I want to transfer my game from one Play store account to other Play store account.
For this purpose, I have started the process and I got this kind of error during the process:

[image]

As per this error, I require to set the price of all in-app products in the currency form of the target account before I made the transfer.

So how to set the price of in-app products as per target account?

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`https://play.google.com >> [choose an app] >> Store presence >> In-app products >>`

Then choose either "Subscriptions" or "Managed product". Then click the arrow next to reach item so you can edit the price.